# Find the next bigger prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is the following a good way or stupid way?

Every odd number can be written as $P=(1+2x)3+(K-3x)2$,
where $x,K$ are $integer>=0$
When $x=0$,
$P=3+2K$,

P is a composite when $(K-3x)$ is divisible by $(1+2x)$.

So if $(K-3x)=y(1+2x), P=2K+3=(1+2x)(3+2y)$ is not a prime.

When $P_m$=biggest known prime number, to find whether $Pm+2$ is prime or not,
let $K=((Pm+2)-3)/2=(Pm-1)/2,$ no matter K is odd or even, check if $(K-3x)$ is divisible by $(1+2x)$ or not. If divisible, set $K=K+1, K+2....$etc until not divisible to find the next prime.

I believe those super computers finding next prime now should have a database of all integers up to $P_m$, odd or even, that which integers can be divided by what prime numbers are already known. Is it?

So just need to compare database to check $(K-3x)$ and $(1+2x)$ where x is about $<=$ square root of $P_m$.

Is this much more time consuming then the current method super computers using?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is much more time consuming. See [Primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) for basic information on this topic.

Comment: "I believe those super computers finding next prime now should have a database of all integers up to Pm, odd or even, that which integers can be divided by what prime numbers are already known. Is it?"  No.  we know some specific very large numbers that are primes without necessarily know all primes that are less than them.... It sounds like you have come up with a sieve method of finding primes.  There's nothing wrong with a sieve method but it can not determine if a number is prime without finding all the primes up to it, with can be time consuming.

Comment: Although I did not fully understand this algorithm, it appears to be like trial division. If so, this method can only sieve out candidates, but a huge number is still almost surely composite, if it has no prime factor below, lets say , $10^{10}$. The chance to get a prime is only $41$ times larger than before ruling out the factors. So, even a supercomputer cannot find another prime efficiently.

Comment: Moreover, huge primes can only be proven to be prime , if they have a special form. Otherwise, we can only get an extremely high chance for primality , for example with Miller-Rabin.

Comment: And finally, there is no way to store the primes upto , lets say, $10^{300}$. The primes upto this number do not fit into the observable universe, no supercomputer can store them and the time to compute them all (although a single test is finished quickly) is much larger than the time left for our sun to become a red giant.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Actually I had ask for if there exist any way to solve the equation (K−3x)=y(1+2x) without plotting graph. If we can know there are no integer solution for x and y, then we can know 2K+3 is a prime. Sadly it seems not possible. Algebra, calculus, geometry, etc, any way can solve the equation?